# how to execute Quickfix/J jar?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, quickfix, quickfixj

I'm building a self contained trading simulator using the quickfix/j library. Up untill now I'd been using mvn package, then the intelli J "Run button" to run my program from an entry point within my client-application class. I tried using the `java -jar target/.....1.1.0.jar` . and get the following error

```
java -jar Broker/target/Broker-1.0.0.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class Broker.ClientApplication
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: quickfix/Application
```

I thought the error might have something to do with my pom file not fetching a dependecy properly. So to make sure I ran the *ordermatch* example from the quickfix/J github, but i get a similar error.

```
java -jar /homes/antonga/IdeaProjects/Desktop/quickfixj-parent/quickfixj-examples/ordermatch/target/quickfixj-examples-ordermatch-2.1.1-sources.jar

no main manifest attribute, in /homes/antonga/IdeaProjects/Desktop/quickfixj-parent/quickfixj-examples/ordermatch/target/quickfixj-examples-ordermatch-2.1.1-sources.jar
```

To be clear using the Intellli J "Run" button inside the main calss works percfectly even for the ordermacth example. From what I gather the command IntelliJ uses is something like this 
`"/path/to/java/" "-javagent/.../.jar" "/pathtolocalmavenrepo/quickfix-core.jar "/pathtolocalmavenrepo/anotherquickfixdependecy.jar" ....."more quickfix dependency jar files" packagestructure.Main`

I don't see why this would work but my execution wouldn't. I can include my pom files and other info if this would help. I'm also using a multi-module maven project but that doesn't seem to the problem.

Comment: When you run from Intellij, this works since the IDE includes all necessary jar-s in the classpath. in order to run from the command line using the `java -jar ..` option, one way to go is to create an "uber-jar" to package all necessary binaries; see the SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Comment: You should not try to run the sources JAR. There should be a standalone JAR for the examples that will run with java -jar.

Comment: You would need to include the quickfixj jars to the classpath: `java -classpath <list-of-all-jars> <main-class>`. Where `<list-of-all-jars>` is a ; (Windows) or : (*nix) separated list of all jars needed to run your program (quickfixj jars, your own jar and any jars needed), and `<main-class>` is the fully qualified class name of your main class (the class that has the main entry to your application).

Comment: @Daniele Thanks. I followed your answer and it worked! I thought I knew maven but turns out I was being a noob. :)

Comment: @ChristophJohn Thanks I didn't properly look at the pom, otehrwise I would have realised the standalone jar is the one I needed to run. Also I'd Iike to say thank you, I've asked other questions and you've been very helpful.

Comment: @TT thanks. Your explanation made it crystal clear . I hope you don't mind, I've used your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was beeing a noob. The Maven package lifecycle bundles the specified class files without the dependencies into a jar. I needed to create an uber jar with all the necessary bianries, and then run that. See the SO question [create excecutable jar with dependencies using maven](http://https:stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

What is required is the following:

```
java -classpath <list-of-all-jars> <main-class>
```

Where `<list-of-all-jars>` is a ; (Windows) or : (*nix) separated list of all jars needed to run your program (quickfixj jars, your own jar and any jars needed), and `<main-class>` is the fully qualified class name of your main class (the class that has the main entry to your application)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an executable jar.
You can use Maven to do this. In your pom.xml can use maven-assembly-plugin to generate your executable jar

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>myour.main.Class</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```